# Parsing text for specific values to create JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert text file entries into a JSON object however I am having trouble understanding how to look for certain values. Given the text document sample:

"get rf_da

Device Timestamp, 6/16/2015 2:14:48 PM"

How would I find the value of the date and the string **following** "get" using Javascript.

Comment: why you don't send the serialized JSON from server?

Comment: The data resides in old text files. The code will never be used to parse anything other than documents that were created months ago.

Comment: You need to define specific rules in order to do anything like that. Artificial Intelligence is out of scope for this question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a regular expression, for example, the following line would retrieve the date string following the text after the 'get'.

`var textFileLine = "get rf_da /n Device Timestamp, 6/16/2015 2:14:48 PM"; 
var lineAfterGetRegEx = /(get)([\w|\s|\n]+)(Device Timestamp,\s)([^"]+)/g;
var lineAfterGetMatch = lineAfterGetRegEx.exec(textFileLine); alert(lineAfterGetMatch[4]);`

From there, you can refine the regular expression above to retrieve the date. Here is a handy online regex tester you can use:
https://regex101.com/

For more details, see the following links:
[How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: hmmm figured regular expressions were the way to go. I was hoping for something like "grab the text after this keyword" type deal. But this will do fine thank you!